# (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape

Tags: python-3.x, colors

I try to import xcolor package:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{xcolor}"]
```

and I have an error:

```
  File "test.py", line 336
    rc('text.latex', preamble="\usepackage{color}")
                             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape
```

How to solve it, please?

The reason why I am doing this is to color text:

```
ax.text3D(2.3e-15, -7.02e-15, 1.65e-14, r'$x \textcolor{white}{r}$')
```

Thank you

Comment: try to change it to a '\. I think the "\ is an escape sequence for unicode.

Comment: '\ didn't work for me, but adding an extra \ did. So `rc('text.latex', preamble="\\usepackage{color}")`